# data transfer using JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get a piece of data from server using JSP technology. I am using JSON object to do so. On client side i am using XMLHttpRequest to get the data.

To check whether it works properly, i wrote a piece of code as follow:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function test(data) {
 if(data){
     var jsonObj= eval('(' + data + ')');
     var Question= jsonObj.Question;
     document.write(Question);
 }
}

function handler() {
 if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  // so far so good
  if(this.responseText != null && this.responseText)
     // success!
   test(this.responseText);
  else
   test(null);
 } else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status != 200) {
  // fetched the wrong page or network error...
  test(null);
 }
}
function xyz(){
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange = handler;
client.open("POST", "fetch.jsp", true);
client.send();
}
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <br><br><input  id="Q" type="button" onclick="xyz()" >
    </body>
```

on server side i did as follow:

```
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <% JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject();
           jsonObj.put("Question","What is your name?");
           jsonObj.put("Opt1","ji");
           jsonObj.put("Opt2","ji");
           jsonObj.put("opt3","ma");
           jsonObj.put("opt4","sa");

      String str= jsonObj.toString();
      response.setContentType("text/plain");
      response.getWriter().write(str);

%>
```

Unfortunately i am not able to get the response.

Comment: `text/plain` should be `application/json`

Comment: Don't use `eval`, get a proper JSON parser: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your JSON into the body of an HTML document, and then sending the HTML document as the response.

Don't do that. The response should be **just** the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write with content type application/json.

Also don't use eval in test function.

When the data is json the test function can access the data as the json object!

In the event of parsing a string use.

```
JSON.parse(string).
```

But don't use eval

Comment: when i set the content type as json, is it necessary to convert json object to string...
and thanx for help